# How to unbind events of dynamic elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following to bind `click` event on certain elements that are inserted into DOM on the fly.

```
jQuery('#cont').on('click', '.myElement1', ....);
```

In this case, how would I `unbind` them?

For what it's worth, `jQuery('.myElement1').unbind('click')` isn't working, as in the code inside the click event is executing multiple times because the `click` events are being registered multiple times.

Comment: jQuery('#cont').off().on('click', '.myElement1', ....);

Comment: @ShreeKhanal that will stop the event handler working on any future `.myElement1` instances

Comment: What would `jQuery('#cont').off()` do? Would it remove events on every element inside of it?

Comment: @asprin It is recommended to use `off` instead of `unbind`. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Comment: How many classes named 'myElement1' do you have in your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot unbind the event handler on `.myElement1` as it was bound to `#cont`. There's no way to remove the event from that single `.myElement1` instance without affecting all the other ones.

What you could do as a workaround is to add another class to the `.myElement` and then exclude that class from the dynamic selector:

```js
$('#cont').on('click', '.myElement1:not(.ignore)', function() {
  console.log('Foo clicked');
});

$('.add').click(function() {
  var $div = $('<div>Foo</div>').appendTo('#cont');
  $div.addClass($(this).data('class'));
});
```

```css
.ignore { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="add" data-class="myElement1">Add clickable</button>
<button type="button" class="add" data-class="myElement1 ignore">Add unclickable</button>
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**the answare is :**

```
jQuery('#cont').off('click', '.myElement1');
```

but if you have many elements and many events inside #cont (#cont have child and grandchild and soon) you can do this:

```
jQuery('#cont').off('', '');
```

That's all

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `jQuery('.myElement1').off('click')` or `.off()`

That should remove the eventHandler.

Comment: This will not work for two reasons. Firstly the event handler is not on `myElement1`, it's delegated to `#cont`. Secondly, if you call off on the delegated element it would remove the handler for *all* `.myElement1` instances, not just the specific ones the OP wants to target